# jQuery autocomplete specific keyup issue

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got an input field with jQuery autocomplete.

```
jQuery("body").on("keyup", "." + AUTOCOMPLETE_CLASS_NAME, 
function (e) {

if (e.keyCode === 65))
{
    jQuery(this).autocomplete({
        width: 300,
        max: 10,
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 3,
        autoFocus: true,
        scroll: true,
        highlight: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: window.autocompleteServletUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
                data: {
                    term: myValue,
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var items = data;
                    if (items.length === 0) {
                        //do stuff
                    }
                    else if (items.length === 1) {
                        //do other stuff
                    }
                    else {
                        response(items); 
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                },
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //do select stuff
        }
    });
}
});
```

My goal is to only show the autocomplete options if the user pressed the button "a".
With the IF statement after the line `jQuery(this).autocomplete` immidiately quits the function without any error, but as soon as I remove the IF statement it works perfectly. But in that way I cannot check if the user pressed button "a" or not.
Can someone help me what is the problem?

Comment: it looks like if you don't press a the code wont run

Comment: yes, that is my goal. it only runs after you press "a". But with the IF statement the autocomplete is not working. As soon as I remove the IF statement (in that way it obviously runs on every keyup) everything works fine. But I don't know why it doesn't work with my if.

Comment: have you put your code in document ready?

Comment: no. why would that help?